How can I modify a URDF file for a KUKA robot?
In the ROS industrial GitHub section,there is the URDF file for the KUKA KR 120 R2500 only.
https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/tree/melodic-devel/kuka_kr120_support
I would like to work with the KR 120 R2700. How can I edit the URDF file in order to get the reach I want?

did you find out how you can get the (inertia, mass, dimensions etc), I want to do the same with KR 120 R2700-2, I have only the STL files , but not the .dea files

In principal this is possible.
You would need to re-write the URDF (probably automated using .xacro) to match the  physical properties (inertia, dimensions etc.) for the KR 120 R2700. The provided .urdf for the KR 120 R2500 would be a good starting point.
Also, you would need the KR 120 R2700-specific .dae files for visualization, which Kuka might not (want to) publish.

How can I get the new inertia and lengths of the links? Do these data appear in the technical data sheet you can get from the Kuka website?

Probably not. Try first with some "close-enough"-values and stick to the information given with the other robots - at least it will be somewhat realistic. In parallel I would ask for the details from Kuka, in the issues of the git repo you linked. Givent the contributors of the git repo and the README hinting it's testing to be included in the Kuka repos, they will be willing to help.
